# Auto Slideshow with pure JS

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

I need to write code for auto slideshow js without library.But i got stuck how to get children of div with class name.(new to web development)

```
    <button onclik="creatslideshow">aaa</button>



<p id="demo"></p>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="img/kitten_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/kitten_2.jpg">
        <img src="img/kitten_3.jpg">
        <img src="img/kitten_4.jpg">
        <img src="img/kitten_5.jpg">
</div>

<script>
let elem1 = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
createSlideshow(elem1);


var createSlideshow = function(slideshowElem) {

    let d = slideshowElem.children.length;//.children;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;


};
</script>
```

Comment: Please show all your code. I do not see any javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, run this script, do what you will with the children but this is how you get them in vanilla js.

```
let parent = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow');
let children = parent[0].children;
console.log('Slideshow elem: ', parent);
console.log('Children elems: ', children);
```

The first line, selects your `slideshow` div element by its class name.

The following line `let children = parent[0].children;` will get the all of the children elements (returned as an array)for the parent. Note here that we are selecting at position `[0]`, as we are looking for the first instance of an element with the classname `slideshow`.

Another way you could select the slideshow element is by id, for example

```
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
```

and then in the js

```
let x = document.getElementById('slideshow');
```

If you go into your developer tools for your browser, and look at the first log message, if you drill down the element, you can see all of the attributes related to that element.

Happy hacking :)

Comment: this answer would be a lot better if you explained it to OP